# Can we create semaphore for multiple conditions

Tags: semaphore, freertos

I have a situation in my application where based on the different notifications I have to put a semaphore. Thing is that if I get type 1 notification, the semaphore should get by different portion of code.

Example:

```
void funcNotify(int notify)
{
   switch(notify)
   {
      case type1:
         Rtos_SemaphorePut(nitificationSemaphore, 1)
         break;
      case type2:
         Rtos_SemaphorePut(nitificationSemaphore, 1)
         break;
      case type3:
         Rtos_SemaphorePut(nitificationSemaphore, 1)
         break;
      default:
         break;
   }
}
```

So my question is can we create a semaphore which can be used for multiple notifications? And based on what type of notification I get, I will execute the required code for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [freeRTOS event_groups](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Event-Groups.html#event_groups) gave me the solution for this issue. I could set individual bits for each notification. Thanks.